# Each Child in a list needs a key prop, React

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting the key prop error and have tried several solutions to fix it. I tried the key={i} prop, and dropping the .name in the example below on a suggestion from a google search. Not sure why this isn't working, when the rest of the code works great. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
   <Col className="coin-links">
          <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">{cryptoDetails.name} Links</Title>
          {cryptoDetails.links?.map((link) => (
            <Row className="coin-link" key={link.name}>
              <Title level={5} className="link-name">{link.type}</Title>
              <a href={link.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">{link.name}</a>
            </Row>
          ))}
        </Col>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code: which part of it is going wrong, [and what is the actual error](/help/how-to-ask)? And if it's "all of it" then just pick a [mcve] from amonghst them and then talk about that on its own. Try to focus your question. But on a React note: [don't use `key={i}`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), the whole point of the key attribute is identify _the thing itself_ so that React can detect whether an element got added, got removed, or _moved around_ in your array. Using an array index literally undoes that, it's worse than not using a key attribute.

Comment: You are missing `key` props in a lot of your `map` renders, have a look at [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) from React docs. As mentioned, the key value should be unique to the elements being rendered so including something unique to each item as part of the key is a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

The `link.name` may not be unique. That's why you are getting the error. You can make you of `link.url` since it's more likely unique.

```js
<Col className="coin-links">
   <Title level={3} className="coin-details-heading">{cryptoDetails.name} Links</Title>
   {cryptoDetails.links?.map((link) => (
         <Row className="coin-link" key={link.url}>
           <Title level={5} className="link-name">{link.type}</Title>
           <a href={link.url} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">{link.name}</a>
         </Row>
    ))}
</Col>
```

Comment: Except that, as mentioned by @mike-pomax-kamermans above " don't use key={i}, the whole point of the key attribute is identify the thing itself so that React can detect whether an element got added, got removed, or moved around in your array. Using an array index literally undoes that, it's worse than not using a key attribute." Dealing with links, I would use the link URL as an identifier rather than its name since the URL is more likely unique.

Comment: I love this explanation. Thank you!